# Android: changing ProgressBar visibility not working

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar in my layout using data binding:

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sov_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32999998"
            app:ui_state_loading="@{viewModel.UIState}"/>
```

The binding adapter looks like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("ui_state_loading")
internal fun setUIStateForLoadingContent(view: View, repositoryResult: RepositoryResult<*>) {
Timber.tag("PROGRESS_BAR").d("binding adapter thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

view.visibility = when (repositoryResult) {
    is RepositoryResult.Loading -> View.VISIBLE
    else -> View.INVISIBLE
}
```

}

The binding class is created like so:

```
        _binding = FragmentRoutesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false).apply {
        lifecycleOwner = this@RoutesFragment
        viewModel = mViewModel
```

UIState is a LiveData created in my ViewModel:

```
    private val _UIState: MutableLiveData<RepositoryResult<CityData>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<RepositoryResult<CityData>>().also {
        it.value = RepositoryResult.Loading()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val repositoryResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                mRepository.getCityData().run {
                    val cityData = this.data!!
                    routesFromJson = cityData.routes
                    poisFromJson = cityData.pointsOfInterest

                    // Code to get all the pois to copy in SearchSuggestionsContentProvider
                    /*val depoList = poisFromJson
                    var pois: String = ""
                    depoList?.forEach {
                        pois += "\"${it.name}\","
                    }
                    Timber.d(pois)*/

                    this
                }
            }

            it.value = repositoryResult
        }
    }

}

override val UIState: LiveData<RepositoryResult<CityData>> = _UIState
```

Now, debugging my app I see that the binding adapter method is correctly called 2 times (both in the main thread), and the 2 options are covered (first visible, then invisible, with a few hundreds of milliseconds between the two), but the ProgressBar remains visibile on the screen.
I tried to replace the ProgressBar with an ImageView, and the problem remains.
I don't know what's the reason. Maybe I'm changing the visibility too quickly?

**UPDATE**
I tried with a TextView: changing the text works, changing the visibility not...

**UPDATE2**
I solved the problem changing the alpha value of the View. However I don't know why changing the visibility property does not work.

Comment: Have you declared your progress bar as part of a constraint layout `Group`?

Comment: The ProgressBar is in a MotionLayout (in the motion scene there is no reference to the ProgressBar).

Answer (score 0):

Use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: How about you set default visibility of progress bar to gone and then manage it's visibility.
android:visibility="gone"